# Как это работает в Yii2?

Tags: yii2

Наткнулся на гитхабе на модельку со следующим кодом: [ССЫЛКА](https://github.com/lmribeiro/curtos.pt/blob/master/models/LoginForm.php)

Вопрос простой - почему в самом начале файла не подключена модель User при помощи такой строки:

```
use app\models\User;
```

Автор файла на 83 строке напрямую обращается к этой модели:

```
$this->_user = User::findByUsername($this->username);
```

Разве это не должно вызвать ошибку? Сможет ли Yii найти эту модель?

Просто всегда использовал use, а тут увидел, что можно и без него...

Answer (score 0):

Если класс находится в том же пространстве имён, то подключать через `use` его не нужно